# sql oracle - constraint on 2 columns from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I have designed a ticket system booking for flights. I want to add a constraint such that the number of tickets you can insert to be less than number of seats from a flight plane.

Let's say I inserted a flight with a plane with 10 seats. I can insert only 10 tickets for that particular flight. Otherwise, an error message should appear.

I tried to make a trigger using the count function on flight number.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ticket_BRIU 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Ticket 
    FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    l_numberofseats flight.numberofseats%type;
BEGIN
    select numberofseats into l_numberofseats
    from flight
    where flightnumber=:new.flightnumber;

    IF :new.count(flightnumber) > l_numberofseats
    THEN
        raise_application_error(-2000, 'Not enough seats');
    END IF;
END;
```

but I get this error

```
Trigger TRG_TICKET_BRIU compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
8/5       PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.COUNT'
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: there is no such thing as a "COUNT" attribute on a bind variable.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would add an `AIRCRAFT` and a `SEAT` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE aircraft (
  id           NUMBER
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
               CONSTRAINT aircraft__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  tail_number  VARCHAR2(6)
               NOT NULL
               CONSTRAINT aircraft__tn__u UNIQUE
               CONSTRAINT aircraft__tn_chk CHECK(
                 REGEXP_LIKE(
                   tail_number,
                   '[A-Z]\d{1,5}|[A-Z]\d{1,4}[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d{1,3}[A-Z]{2}'
                 )
               ),
  manufacturer VARCHAR2(20)
               NOT NULL,
  model        VARCHAR2(20)
               NOT NULL,
  airline_id   CONSTRAINT aircraft__aid__fk REFERENCES airline(airline_id)
               NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE seat (
  id           NUMBER
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
               CONSTRAINT seat__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  aircraft_id  CONSTRAINT seat__aid__fk REFERENCES aircraft(id)
               NOT NULL,
  seat_row     VARCHAR2(3)
               NOT NULL,
  seat_column  NUMBER
               NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT seat__aid_r_c__u UNIQUE (aircraft_id, seat_row, seat_column)
);
```

Then your `flight` table would reference the `aircraft`:

```
CREATE TABLE flight (
  id           NUMBER
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
               CONSTRAINT flight__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  aircraft_id  CONSTRAINT flight__aid__fk REFERENCES aircraft(id)
               NOT NULL
  -- ...
);
```

And the `ticket` would reference a `flight` and a `seat`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ticket (
  id           NUMBER
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
               CONSTRAINT ticket__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  flight_id    CONSTRAINT ticket__fid__fk REFERENCES flight(id)
               NOT NULL,
  seat_id      CONSTRAINT ticket__sid__fk REFERENCES seat(id)
               NOT NULL,
  -- ...
  CONSTRAINT ticket__fid_sid__u UNIQUE (flight_id, seat_id)
);
```

Then you can never sell a `seat` that does not exist on an `aircraft` and do not need to count the maximum number of tickets and compare it to seats (and the `seat` has added attributes like its location on the plane that can be displayed on the ticket).

All you need then is to ensure the referential consistency that, for a `ticket`, the `flight` and the `seat` are on the same `aircraft`; which can be done with a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ticket_check_seat_on_flight
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ticket
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  is_valid NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   is_valid
  FROM   flight f
         INNER JOIN seat s
         ON (f.aircraft_id = s.aircraft_id)
  WHERE  f.id = :NEW.flight_id
  AND    s.id = :NEW.seat_id;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
      -20000,
      'Flight and seat are on different aircraft.'
    );
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=659ec800cf3432343f0dc32082616be9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AFTER STATEMENT` trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ticket__check_number_of_seats
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON ticket
DECLARE
  is_invalid NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   is_invalid
  FROM   flight f
         INNER JOIN (
           SELECT flight_id,
                  COUNT(*) AS tickets_sold
           FROM   ticket
           GROUP BY flight_id
         ) t
         ON f.id = t.flight_id
  WHERE  t.tickets_sold > f.number_of_seats;
  
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(
    -20000,
    'Too many tickets sold for flight.'
  );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

It could be made more efficient by using a compound trigger to collate, for each row, the `flight_id` values into a collection and then, after the statement, only checking the number of tickets for those flights; however, I'll leave that extension as an exercise for the OP.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=054f47db8dd219cc90873ba404c49d9d)*

Answer (score 0):

As others indicated there is no :new.count column. This is because :new (and :old) create a pseudo-row containing exactly the same columns as the table definition.  Further you will get a `Mutating` exception as what you need to count in the `flight_number` from `tickets`. However, since that is the table causing he trigger to fire you cannot reference it. So what to do: create a [compound trigger](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374), and a supporting Type (nested table). Within it use the `after row` section to capture the flight_numbers processed. Then in the `after statement` section you can select count of tickets for each flight. If that count > 0 then raise your exception. ( see [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fe676e49a46181da2ca7ff908295e761) )

```
create type flight_tickets_ntt
         is table of integer;

create or replace trigger trg_ticket_ciu
   for update or insert on tickets
       compound trigger
       
    l_flights  flight_tickets_ntt := flight_tickets_ntt(); 
    
    after each row is 
    begin 
        if :new.flight_number not member of l_flights then 
            l_flights.extend ;
            l_flights(l_flights.count) := :new.flight_number; 
        end if; 
    end after each row; 
    
    after statement is
        l_flight_cnt flight.flight_number%type;
    begin 
         select count(*)
           into l_flight_cnt
           from flight f 
          where f.number_of_seats < 
                ( select count(*)
                    from tickets t 
                   where t.flight_number in 
                         ( select * 
                             from table (l_flights)
                         ) 
                );  
       
          if l_flight_cnt > 0 then 
             raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not enough seats');
          end if; 
           
    end after statement; 
end trg_ticket_ciu;
```

There remains a you need to handle: What happens if an update changes the flight number or perhaps (missing column) the data of the flight.